# Direction of a plane

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

When we write parametric equations of the plane, we can easily find the direction vector. But for example, if the equation is written like this; x+4y+2z-1=0 we can find the normal vector by coefficients (1,4,2). But how can I find the direction and write the vector equation of the plane ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take two vectors perpendicular with the normal vector $\vec {n} $.

for example if
$$\vec {n}=(a,b,c) $$
then
$$\vec{u}=(-b,a,0) $$
and
$$\vec {v}=(-c,0,a) $$
and we are sure they are independent.

> or from cartesian equation
>   $$x=1-4y-2z $$
>   $$y=y $$
>   $$z=z $$
>   from here you have the point $(1,0,0) $ and two vectors director.
>   $$\vec {u}=(-4,1,0)$$
>   $$\vec {v}=(-2,0,1) $$

Comment: I solved my problem now. Thank you very much!

Comment: If the normal vector is $(1,-3,2) $ what are the vector director of the plane.

Comment: u=(3,1,0), v=(-2,0,1)

Comment: @Procardo Very good and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The normal vector $\vec{n}$ is simply the coefficients of $x,y,z$. Then, if you find a point on the plane, $\vec{p}$, the equation of the plane is $n \cdot \vec{x} = n \cdot \vec{p}$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand n.x=n.p part. For this example, x+4y+2z-1=0, the normal vector n=(1,4,2). Then?

Comment: Find a point on the plane ( any point on the plane will work). For example, $(1,0,0)$. That will be $\vec{p}$.